# Does zabbix support "group by" trigger functions

Tags: zabbix

I have an item collecting order activities, the item get order id when the given order encounter a failure, so it should look like this:

```
<timestamp>    <order_id>
               1122
               1122
               1280
               1122
```

I want to get a notification if any order shows up more than 3 times, but I don't find anything like `group by` to collaborate with `count()` in [trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions), just wondering is it possible in zabbix?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger expression like this:

```
{host:order_id.delta(#3)}=0
```

That should trigger whenever there's no difference / delta within the last three measurements.